Fetching data from RPSCO table to get actual spend in the project. SAP PS
I have created this logic to get actual spent amount of projects in SAP PS.
But I need help on this I am unable to fetch data correctly. I need to know how to give logic to get control area currency and separately object currency also.
The logic I provide is to fetch object currency data.
Ledger values are provided in RPSCO table, but I am unable to create logic for this.
Can anyone please me on this.
For PROJ-PSPID = PRPS-PSPHI and for PRPS-BELKZ = "X" we get all WBS elements of lower level with Object no.
Now copy all object number of this WBS elements (PRPS-OBJNR). For RPSCO-OBJNR =PRPS-OBJNR and
if PROJ-PWHIE = "INR" then
RPSCO-LEDNR = '001'
else
if PROJ-PWHIE <> "INR" then
RPSCO-LEDNR <> '001' & RPSCO-LEDNR <>'002' and RPSCO-WRTTP ='4' and RPSCO-VERSN ='0' Find RPSCO-WLP01 to WLP12 of all WBS elements and sum them to get Total Spent OC.
I need to know how the data can be fetched by taking ledger as consideration or is there any other way to get actual spent of the project data from table level to create a logic.
